# Cannot connect to L2tp VPN using windows 10 client but I can connect using ubuntu VMbox from the same windows 10 client

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, l2tp

I cannot connect to L2tp VPN Server using my windows 10 PC. I have VM box installed with Ubuntu on the same windows 10. But the VPN connects from this ubuntu VM.

The VPN server is Windows server 2016

How is this possible? Is there any issue with Windows 10?

[The Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWYFk.png)

Comment: Whether the VPN server is a Windows server? Is there any error message on Windows 10 client when connected to the VPN server?

Comment: yes VPN server is windows server 2016. The error message Updated in the question. I don't know why this website not letting me add the image but its adding only the link.

Comment: Per the screenshot of the error message, I would suggest you disable Windows Firewall and anti-virous software on both VPN server and Window 10 client to test if the issue can be resolved.

Comment: But how come the Ubuntu VM installed on that windows 10 connects to the VPN?